# Oracle insertion with Java spring and hibernate takes too much time

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a microservice that gets an array of objects from an API and then connects with a remote oracle BBDD and inserts the information. In a call, I'd get like 7k-10k registers and it's taking on average to save them 1 hour which is crazy. Why could it be? Is it a problem from the server or I'm doing something wrong?

application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:url
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


spring.data.rest.basePath=/api

spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=springBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=10000
```

The model of the table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CALL")
public class Call {

    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "QUEUEID")
    private String queueId;

    @Column(name = "QUEUETYPE")
    private String queueType;

    @Column(name = "AGENTID")
    private String agentId;

    @Column(name = "DATASET")
    private String dataSet;

    @Column(name = "CALLDATE")
    private Timestamp callDate;

    @Column(name = "CALLDURATION")
    private String callDuration;

    @Column(name = "RINGTIME")
    private String ringTime;

    @Column(name = "RESULT")
    private String result;

    @Column(name = "DATE_LOAD")
    private Date fecCarga = new Date();

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

JAVA LOGIC

The logic is very simple

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String response = reportingServices.getToken();
        Token token = objectMapper.readValue(response, Token.class);
        String tokenString = token.setToken(token.getToken());
        String startDate = req.getStartDate();
        String endDate = req.getEndDate() ;

        final String uri = API_URL 

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("list");

        try{
            for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++)
            {
                JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Call call = new Call();

                String callid = (String) objectInArray.get("callid");
                String qid = (String) objectInArray.get("qid");
                String type = (String) objectInArray.get("type");
                String agent = (String) objectInArray.get("agent");
                String dataset = (String) objectInArray.get("dataset");
                String datetime = (String) objectInArray.get("datetime");
                String duration = (String) objectInArray.get("duration");
                String ringtime = (String) objectInArray.get("ringtime");
                String resultTable = (String) objectInArray.get("result");

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(datetime);
                Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());

                call.setId(callid);
                call.setQueueId(qid);
                call.setQueueType(type);
                call.setAgentId(agent);
                call.setDataSet(dataset);
                call.setCallDate(timestamp);
                call.setCallDuration(duration);
                call.setRingTime(ringtime);
                call.setResult(resultTable);
                call.setFecCarga(call.getFecCarga());

                callRepository.save(call);
            }
            return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(HttpStatus.CREATED, "Info created successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Something went wrong.");
        }
```

Repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface callRepository extends JpaRepository<Call,Long> {
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to share  `callRepository`? Which version of Spring Boot is this?

Comment: I just updated the post with ```callRepository```. Version 2.2.6

Answer (score 1):

Even if you configured `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` it won't help you because you are saving individually each entry of your list. use `saveAll()` method from JpaRepository and save in batches of 100 at least.

Comment: But if you read the code, in each iteration is saving one register, because I have to go through an array of objects. Is it possible to use ```saveAll()``` with the logic I implemented?

Comment: Yes. Create a List<Call> before for loop. After each 100 entries you will insert in batch those entries and clean up the list, and do the same for others.

Comment: and the ```saveAll``` method where would it be?

Comment: Inside for loop from an if statement that is checking the number of elements that you have iterated. Another way would be to execute them concurrently, and even make use of batch insertion also there.
Maybe this can help you: https://persistencelayer.wixsite.com/springboot-hibernate/post/how-to-batch-inserts-in-spring-boot-style-via-completablefuture